# Execute an xcode function with a Unity3D button?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to make a button in unity that will execute a function in Xcode? I'm trying to execute an push message from an unity3d project. Please help cause it's making me crazy...

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Just a little help. Xcode is only the IDE and has nothing todo with the functions or methods that the application will execute. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call native Objective-C code that have a C interface. And even more you can call back methods in Unity3D. Some useful documentation where to start:

[Plugins](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html)

[Building Plugins for iOS](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

There was a demo project and blog posting. This was removed from the original web site, which now does advertising only. The archived version from 2012 can be found here:

[Internet Archive Wayback Machine April 2, 2012: Clever Martian's Blog - An Experiment with iPhone Native UI and Unity 3 Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20120402132456/http://clevermartian.com/blog/)

Comment: the blog is missing. and I had writen another one: [*Use iPhone Native UI in Unity3D*](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jtianling.com%2Farticles%2F2030.html)