# Calculate Free Disk Space On Ipad / Iphone Using Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, diskspace

I have been looking through a lot of different place to find a way to check how much space a user has on his device.
I am developing a game with Unity (C#) for Ipad and I would like to check how much space is available before writing my save game.

This post seems to be the most popular : [How to detect total available/free disk space on the iPhone/iPad device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device)

Unfortunately this is Objective-C and I am way too noob / junior to use it.

I know there are some API available (U3DXT is one of them), but I can't find a way to convert it or make it work. I am not an engineer, so please excuse me in advance if I don't use the correct words to explain what I'd like to do.

If someone could point me in the right direction or have an existing script in C# I could use. I know that DriveInfo.GetDrives() doesn't work on PC, but I saw somewhere it could be working on Mac (Ipad?). At least I will try it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Check this for iOS native
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036586/1031944

and then call this function from unity3d c#
e.g
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568232/1031944

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I never used xcode except to build my unity project, so I'm not sure how to do that. But I should find out. I will let you know :) Thanks.